# BigQuery - quoting strings produced unexpected results

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running the following query:

```
select concat('{','"name"',':', chr(34), str,
              chr(34), ', ','"type"',':','"string"','},') jsonl
from (select 'part_number' as str)
```

which results in:

[image]

and this is the expected results.

But when I save the results to a csv file,
the results look different.

The issue is with the extra double quotation mark that is surrounding each element.

[image]

Any idea what is causing this discrepancy.

btw, my local machine is running Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common escaping for quotes inside strings in csv files. Try opening this file in Excel or LibreOffice Calc. It should look as expected.

[image]

Comment: I need the CSV to look correctly.